# Why is there a difference between the size of these two arrays with the same characters in C?

Tags: arrays, c, character, null-character

I created two arrays 'TEST' and 'arr' below,both contain characters "ABCDE".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TEST  "ABCDE" 
int main()
{
  char arr[5];
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
       arr[i] = i + 65;
  }
  printf("%s\n",arr);
  printf("%zd %zd",sizeof arr,sizeof TEST);
  return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
ABCDE
5 6
```

Why are their size different, given that  these two arrays both carry 5 characters ?
（I konw there is a null character at the end of each character string.)

Comment: "konw there is a null character at the end of each character string.": I am not sure where you think a null character would be in `arr`. Could you explain your reasoning that the two `sizeof` expressions should have the same result?

Comment: I supposed the size of  'arr'  should be 6, but it seems there is no place for 'arr' to store the null character?

Comment: If you tell the compiler that `arr` has five slots, that's what it has. If you then put non-zero characters in all five slits, then you cannot use the array as a string. That's not a problem for the compiler. Arrays don't have to be usable as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the macro expansion, the line

```
printf("%zd %zd",sizeof arr,sizeof TEST);
```

will be:

```
printf("%zd %zd",sizeof arr,sizeof "ABCDE" );
```

String literals will always have a terminating null character added to them. Therefore, the type of the string literal is `char[6]`. The expression `sizeof "ABCDE"` will therefore evaluate to `6`.

However, the type of `arr` is `char[5]`. Space for a null-terminating character will not be automatically added. Therefore, the expression `sizeof arr` will evaluate to `5`.

Also, it is worth noting that the following line is causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
printf("%s\n",arr);
```

The `%s` `printf` format specifier requires a null-terminated string. However, `arr` is not null-terminated.

If you want to print the array, you must therefore limit the number of characters printed to `5`, like this:

```
printf( "%.5s\n", arr );
```

Or, if you don't want to hard-code the length into the format string, you can also do this:

```
printf( "%.*s\n", (int)sizeof arr, arr );
```

Comment: Thanks, I know what my fault is.